# Alternative to Controller.flash in Play! 1.2.4

Tags: error-handling, playframework

I currently use Play Framework's Controller.flash to set my errors before rendering. 
As a result, the displayed error is often shown during 2 navigation steps. It is the expected behaviour since I don't always redirect.

So my question is : Does Play provides a way to handle simple render errors (like flash is handling redirect errors) ?
Or shall I manage my own error parameter ? Or shall I always ensure that I redirect ?

Answer (score 1):

The flash scope is only for redirecting to another page. If you don't redirect, but call the render() method directly, then simply don't use flash. The error will automatically be available in you view.